# How do I generate swagger meta data file from Azure API App solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, swagger, azure-api-apps

I want to generate swagger meta data, so I can generate client code.

I want Azure API App #1 to consume other Azure API App #2 .

Is it possible to generate metadata from locally hosted Azure API before publishing anything to Azure ?

UPDATE : Swagger.json is already generated after running API on my machine. It's located in ...AppData\Local\Temp\WebToolsAutoRest\NameOfSolution... So there was no need to specify explicitly that it should generate meta data, it was already doing it.

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't matter if you are trying to use Swagger on a local API service or in the cloud. Swagger looks at the endpoints and generates the artifacts based on what it sees there. For detailed information check this out:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-dotnet-get-started

Comment: Realized I could just paste url of API hosted on my machine, or point to json generated in client folder in WebToolsAutoRest.  Had a bit of trouble with Newtonsoft, but after that it was fine. Only after failing did I realize it was already generated and I didn't have to do anything else but add it. Thanks for input.